# Creating a single file from multiple files (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I can't figure out a great way to do this, but I have 2 files with a standard date and value format.

```
File 1             File 2
Date Value         Date Value
4     7.0          1     9.0
5     5.5          .     .
6     4.0          7     2.0
```

I want to combine files 1 and 2 to get the following:

```
Combined Files
Date Value1 Value2 Avg
1     NaN    9.0   9.0
2     NaN    9.0   9.0
3     NaN    8.5   8.5
4     7.0    7.5   7.25
5     5.5    5.0   5.25
6     4.0    3.5   3.75
7     NaN    2.0   2.0
```

How would I attempt this? I figured I should make a masked array with the date going from 1 to 7 and then just append the files together, but I don't know how I would do that with file 1. Any help where to look would be appreciated.

Using Python 3.x

EDIT:
I solved my own problem!
I am sure there is a better way to streamline this. My solution, doesn't use the example above, I just threw in my code.

```
def extractFiles(Dir, newDir, newDir2):
    fnames = glob(Dir)
    farray = np.array(fnames)

    ## Dates range from 723911 to 737030
    dateArray = np.arange(723911,737030) # Store the dates
    dataArray = []                       # Store the data, This needs to be a list! Not np.array!

    for f in farray:
        ## Extracting Data
        CH4 = np.genfromtxt(f, comments='#', delimiter=None, dtype=np.float).T

        myData = np.full(dateArray.shape, np.nan) # Create an masked array
        myDate = np.array([])

        ## Converts the given datetime into something more useable
        for x, y in zip(*CH4[1:2], *CH4[2:3]):
            myDate = np.append(myDate,
                              (mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime('{}-{}'.format(int(x), int(y)), '%Y-%m'))))

        ## Finds where the dates are the same and places the approprite concentration value
        for i in range(len(CH4[3])):
            idx = np.where(dateArray == myDate[i])
            myData[idx] = CH4[3, i]

        ## Store all values in the list
        dataArray.append(myData)

    ## Convert list to numpy array and save in txt file
    dataArray = np.vstack((dateArray, dataArray))
    np.savetxt(newDir, dataArray.T, fmt='%1.2f', delimiter=',')

    ## Find the averge of the data to plot
    avg = np.nanmean(dataArray[1:].T,1)
    avg = np.vstack((dateArray, avg))
    np.savetxt(newDir2, avg.T, fmt='%1.2f', delimiter=',')

    return avg
```

Comment: Where does the Date 2 & 3 in your "Combined Files" come from? Can´t see it in your example above

Comment: They come from file 2. I just for a dot there as a place holder to represent a continuation of the data from date 1 to 7. @mgruber

Comment: What file format do you use? How are the files called? Is the number (1 or 2) included in the filename or does it even matter which will be Value1 and Value2. How many files will you have?

Comment: 250 files with about 13k data points in each one. They were all .txt formated. I'm not against using panda, but I wanted to keep within the boundaries of my Course, so that required me to stick with numPy. I used glob to locate a list of files in the for dir (\*month.txt). Then numPy genfromtxt to extract everything.

Comment: And no, it didn't necessarily matter what is value 1 or 2, I just wanted to keep the values from with a derived my results from on the same txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer based on the information you gave me:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# I stored two Excel files in a subfolder of this sample code
# Code
# ----Files
# -------- File1.xlsx
# -------- File2.xlsx

# Here I am saving the path to a variable
file_path = os.path.join(*[os.getcwd(), 'Files', ''])

# I define an empty DataFrame that we then fill we the files information
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

# file_number will be used to increment the Value column based number of files that we load.
# First file will be Value1, second will lead to Value2
file_number = 1

# os.listdir is now "having a look" into the "Files" folder and will return a list of files which is contained in there
# ['File1.xlsx', 'File2.xlsx'] in our case
for file in os.listdir(file_path):
    # we load the Excel file with pandas function "read_excel"
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path + file)
    # Rename the column "Value" to "Value" + the "file_number"
    df = df.rename(columns={'Value': 'Value'+str(file_number)})

    # Check if the Dataframe already contains values
    if not final_df.empty:
        # If there is values already then we merge them together with the new values
        final_df = final_df.merge(df, how='outer', on='Date')
    else:
        # Otherwise we "initialize" our final_df with the first Excel file that we loaded
        final_df = df

    # at the end we increment the file number by one to continue to next file
    file_number += 1

# get all column names that have "Value" in it
value_columns = [w for w in final_df.columns if 'Value' in w]
# Create a new column for the average and build the average on all columns that we found for value columns
final_df['Avg'] = final_df.apply(lambda x: x[value_columns].mean(), axis=1)
# Sort the dataframe based on the Date
sorted_df = final_df.sort_values('Date')

print(sorted_df)
```

The print will output this:

```
   Date  Value1  Value2   Avg
3     1     NaN     9.0  9.00
4     2     NaN     9.0  9.00
5     3     NaN     8.5  8.50
0     4     7.0     7.5  7.25
1     5     5.5     5.0  5.25
2     6     4.0     3.5  3.75
6     7     NaN     2.0  2.00
```

Please be aware that this is not paying attention on the file names and is just loading one file after another based on the alphabet.

But this has the advantage that you can put as many files in there as you want.

If you need to load them in a specific order I can probably help you with that as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was attempting to avoid pandas, but I figured out another way to do it. Although I am sure mine is a bit clunkier. I used txt files, since I am more confident with those. I post my solution in the edit.

Comment: Hi! Is there any specific reason why you are trying to avoid pandas? Please make sure to be more specific about your file formats in the future and what you are trying to avoid. I would be happy if you at least can upvote my comment for my effort :-D

Comment: I upvoted, but this website won't show it because of my low reputation. :(